# What is a word I can use to describe the personality of a company?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a description of my business, which creates websites for companies, and this is what I have so far:

> We think that every one of our clients are unique and deserve a unique website that matches their **[blank]**.

I've thought about using words like *values* or *personality*. But I feel like I've heard a better fit before.

What word would you use?

Comment: Taste, choice, persona... Also, your requirement is too broad. You'll have to narrow it down.

Comment: what kind of word would you specifically prefer?

Comment: Maybe your culture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Company culture** might work.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Organizational_culture) defines this as

> Company vision, values, norms, systems, symbols, language, assumptions, beliefs, and habits.

Comment: That's actually Forbes quoting Wikipedia's article on "organisational culture".

Comment: This might be a good option for you, http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/corporate-culture.asp

Comment: Isn't culture more of an internal thing?  Unless you *want* your potential customers to feel part of the company culture, that is.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Assuming that the term is more than business psychobabble, the culture of a company would be an internal thing, but so would be the components of an individual's personality.  Nothing says that the internal makeup isn't reflected outwardly.  In any case, the request was for something that would convey making the company comfortable, not its customers.

Comment: "We think that every one of our clients are unique and deserve a unique website that matches their [blank]." - to me this sounds like the product they are trying to sell is **public-facing** websites for companies.  Anyway, i didn't mean to sound too critical, i was just exploring the meaning.

Comment: @deadrat Ah, Forbes and ad-block. Btw, shouldn't you edit to add the real source here? Forbes didn't define it that way, [Wikipedia did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_culture). :)

Answer (score 2):

How about [ethos](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ethos)?

> The disposition, character, or fundamental values peculiar to a specific person, people, culture, or movement

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*

Answer (score 2):

(Corporate) identity

> A corporate identity is the manner [in] which a corporation, firm or business presents themselves to the public, such as customers and investors as well as employees.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_identity)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using "[characteristic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/characteristic)".

> a special quality or trait that makes a person, thing, or group
>   different from others

Your example:

> We think that every one of our clients are unique and deserve a unique
>   website that matches their **characteristics**.

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 1):

***organizational culture*** — ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/organizational-culture))

> *noun* 1.the customs, rituals, and values shared by the members of an organization that have to be accepted by new members

***mission statement***

> A written declaration of an organization's core purpose and focus that
>   normally remains unchanged over time. [(business dictionary)](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/mission-statement.html)

***vision statement***

> An aspirational description of what an organization would like to
>   achieve or accomplish in the mid-term or long-term future. It is
>   intended to serves as a clear guide for choosing current and future
>   courses of action. [(business dictionary)](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/vision-statement.html)

Answer (score 1):

*We think that every one of our clients are unique and deserve a unique website that matches their **character**.*

[No reference because *character* is not exactly a rare word.]

Answer (score 1):

**Core ideology** could work here. It successfully captures all the aspects of a company that make up its 'personality.'

> [Core Ideology](http://www.strategystream.com/questions/core-ideology/) -  the Mission, Vision, & Values of a business entity

Answer (score 1):

Company ***[values](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/value?q=values#value__4)*** or ***[core values](http://fortune.com/2015/03/13/company-slogans/)***.

> Principles or standards of behaviour